# Узнать координаты центра прямоугольника после поворота и смещения

Tags: геометрия, график, координаты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]У меня есть координаты прямоугольника ABCD и его угол поворота. у меня есть координата клика -  точка g. По клику рисуется зеленый прямоугольник с известными координатами и добавляется к черному прямоугольнику левым верхним углом - точкой g. Мне нужно добиться прилегания зеленого прямоугольника к черному, как это нарисовано голубым. Позиционирование прямоугольника происходит через его центр - в зеленом это точка P.
вопрос - как найти точку X?
Спасибо за подсказки, советы и направления, в какую сторону копать)

Comment: Координаты точек D и C найти сможете? А еще лучше, задать прямоугольник координатами вершин (вместо координат центра и угла поворота)

Answer (score 2):

В векторном виде:

```
x = g + (d-a) / |d-a| * половину высоты голубого
```

(из описания неясно, как задаются размеры голубого и зеленого, возможно, нужная величина - `(g.y-p.y)` )

Answer (score 1):

Сначала надо найти точку отсчета. Пусть она будет по середине между точками `C` и `D`

```
ox = cx + (dx - cx) / 2
oy = cy + (dy - cy) / 2
```

Дальше нужно получить угол поворота относительно прямоугольника

```
ang = Math.atan2(dx - cx, dy - cy) + Math.PI / 2
```

Здесь `+ Math.PI / 2` - это прямой угол от наклоненной линии. Там он либо `+` либо `-`. Попробовать оба варианта.

Дальше посчитаем полу-высоту прямоугольника:

```
radix = (gy - my) / 2
```

И посчитаем саму точку центра прямоугольника:

```
centerX = ox + radix * Math.sin(ang)
centerY = oy - radix * Math.cos(ang)
```

Если не запутался нигде, то вроде все верно